# Step and Mongodb driver @ Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
Step(
                function findFilters() {
                    database.connection.collection("diary_filter").find(this);
                },
                function loopFilters(error, cursor) {
                    var group = this.group();
                    cursor.each(group());
                },
                function testFilters(err, filters) { 
                    console.log("here we are", filters.length);
                }
            );
```

testFilters recieves an array of lenght 1, even though there are n filters. Any thoughts on what Im doing wrong? Or any suggestions on how to handle async code better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do the trick?

```
Step(
    function findFilters() {
        database.connection.collection("diary_filter").find().toArray(this);
    },
    function testFilters(err, filters) { 
        console.log("here we are", filters.length);
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

this will never work as step will not interact correctly and it's not meant to be used this way.

rewrite it not using step and to toArray since you are pulling back all the items anyway

```
database.connection.collection("diary_filter").find().toArray(function(err, items) {});
```

Comment: -1. "*this will never work as step will not interact correctly and it's not meant to be used this way.*" This is not even coherent. There's nothing **inherently** wrong with @Peeter using Step here; maybe there's more code omitted which needs to continue on afterwards. Even your example here could be integrated into a Step, despite your claim that it will "never work".